# Not able to save the image created using php

Tags: php, jpeg

I am adding some text to an image using PHP and then outputting it using:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($rImg, NULL, 100);
```

The image is displayed correctly, but when I right click to save the image, it saves it as a PHP file and not an image. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have add a header for the file name

example:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="new_image.jpg"');
```

(can use 'inline' or 'attachment')